# Get hours in source timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

Suppose I've an ISO string date; Is there any simple api in JS or MomentJS to extract the hour in the original timezone (not the local, not the UTC):

```
//eg

2020-04-01T05:00:00+02:00 -> 7
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the original timezone"?

Comment: the one specified in the string: "+02:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't make sense. For the timestamp that expresses the time "5 am" in timezone +0200, the "hour in the original timezone" is *5*. Because that's the time your timestamp expresses. The hour in UTC would be **3**, because at the time it's 5 am in timezone +0200, it's 3 am in UTC.

```js
 
const tz = moment('2020-04-01T05:00:00+02:00');
console.log(tz.hour());
console.log(tz.utc().hour());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

To get *7* out of this, you'd need to convert the timestamp to timezone +0400; at the time it's 5 am in +0200, it's 7 am in +0400. But that's entirely arbitrary and has nothing to do with any "original timezone".

Comment: I see, I didn't catch the real meaning of the ISODate string.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No".

Strings are parsed to a time value that is an offset from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (the ECMAScript epoch), so are effectively UTC. The date instance created has no knowledge of how it was created, so it's impossible to use a Date instance to recover any information from the original string used to generate it.

You have to parse the string yourself to get any values from it (a library might help, I think [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) might dot it), e.g. to get the original hour:

```js
['2020-05-12T08:23:15.000+05:30',
 '2020-05-12T08:23:15.000-0400',
 '2020-05-12T08:23:15.000Z'].forEach(ts => {
let [year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond, offset] = ts.match(/^\d+|\d\d\d|\d\d|Z$|[+-]\d\d:?\d\d$/g);
console.log(
`year      : ${year}
month     : ${month}
day       : ${day}
hour      : ${hour}
minute    : ${minute}
second    : ${second}
millsecond: ${millisecond}
offset    : ${offset}
`);
});
```

Where the offset is expressed per ISO 8601 (e.g. +07:00 or +0700) then it's a fixed offset and will not reflect historic or daylight saving changes that might apply for the system that generated it, so it should only be applied to that specific date and time.